# How to post parameters to java servlet using curl from php page?

Tags: java, php, mysql, servlets, curl

I am working on a web application using Netbeans. My PHP page consists of a form which contains username and password which i have to validate in **PHP** using **MySQL** and send those parameters to Servlet using **curl**. I am able to receive the data at the servlet but i cannot progress furthur i.e **flow of control returns to PHP page again and displays error on the web page that the requested resource is not available(RequestDispatcher is not forwading properly i guess.)**

What i've tried is as follows.

**HTML**

```
 <form id="loginform" name="loginform" method="POST" action="HomePage.php">
 <input type="text" id="user_name" name="user_name">
 <input type="password" id="password" name="password">
 <input type="submit" >
```

**PHP**

```
    <?php
    // After validating 
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost:8080/WebApp/Validatelogin");//validatelogin is a servlet
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "email=" . $email . "pass=" . $pass);
        curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
     ?>
```

**validateLogin.java**

```
        email = request.getParameter("email").trim();
        Password= request.getParameter("pass");
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("./mainpage.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);

  Error : mainpage is not available.
```

Anyone please help me as i am newbie to PHP.Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that **CURL** doesn't redirect to another resource,it only fetches the data from another resource(websites). I have used PHP simplest method **header** to redirect to a  servlet in my web application.It solved my problem.

```
header("Location: http://localhost:8080/WebApp/Validatelogin?email=$email");
```

Answer (score 1):

Handle redirect from your php as you are redirecting from your java.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
```

Also, if you want to see the output from your php, use return-transfer option

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @Sabuj Hassan. I will try that one.

Comment: That didn't work @Sabuj Hassan . Getting same error : the requested URL /mainpage.jsp was not found on this server.

Comment: Possibly the error from your server side which i have less knowledge about that. However, from curl end, you can enable the verbose mode and run the script `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);`. It will display you the things actually curl is doing when you execute it.

Comment: Where do i see the log of curl??

Comment: @Krish the log can be at your browser, console or at server log.